# Convention of member routes with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an action (**:my_action**) route that will allow me to capture the current object :id as well as a :client_id.

For new records, the url would look like this:

```
controller/action/new/my_action/:client_id
```

For editing existing records, the url would look like this:

```
controller/action/:id/edit/my_action/:client_id
```

I have played around with member routes but can't seem to get it working for both of the above scenarios.

Thanks in advance =]

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily declare two routes and direct them both to `my_action`

```
map.connect 'controller/action/new/my_action/:client_id', :controller => :my_controller, :action => :my_action
map.connect 'controller/action/:id/edit/my_action/:client_id', :controller => :my_controller, :action => :my_action
```

Seems like the easiest solution to me.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you!